# RubyMine autosave on loss of focus

Tags: textmate, rubymine

I previously had textmate set up to save when I lossed focus (i.e. navigated to a different application, terminal etc.)

Is there anyway to set RubyMine up to do this?

Comment: On a side question, Can you tell me how tell us how to set up autosave for Textmate (MacOS) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[File | Settings | General |](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/general-2.html) Save files on frame deactivation:

> Select this check box to have all modified files saved every time you switch to another application.
>   Clearing the check box may cause a conflict of changes within and outside RubyMine when it loses the focus. In this case, RubyMine will prompt you to select the desired revision. See the File Cache Conflict dialog box reference for details.

[image: Save files on frame deactivation]

Note that this option should be already enabled by default.

Comment: I only see preferences, where are settings located?

Comment: Updated my reply with the documentation link.

Comment: Rubymine is a really nice editor which I keep coming back to.